# How to download all repositories of a GitHub account to my personal computer without using github cli?

Tags: command-line, backup, git, download, github

I use WSL Ubuntu 18.04 unchanged.

I have one GitHub user with 6 GitHub repositories of that user.

Basically I just need to download all my GitHub repositories as I wish to make a local backup of all my GitHub repositories in my personal computer.

I can download a zip of each one of all 6 repositories from **GitHub GUI** but I seek some automatic way to download all of them from CLI, not necessarily in zip form (it can also be just 6 directories with all files in them).

How will I achieve this?

Comment: Doesn’t the answer to [your previous question on this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701801/86440) address this?

Comment: Technically you’re asking for archives here, but the archives you can download from GitHub don’t contain your repositories, they only contain the files in the current tip of the repository (or whatever branch or tag they’re created from). If you want a backup, you should archive the repositories.

Comment: @StephenKitt I am not sure, I don't think I want to use GitHub CLI, I am looking just to download the most recent files. Perhaps I should rephrase the question somehow. Maybe you have an idea how.

Comment: Is it worth writing a script to query GitHub for the repositories if you only have 6 of them? You could copy&paste the 6 names from the website and create a command like `for r in repo1 repo2 ... repo6; do git clone https://github.com/username/$r.git; done`. (Assuming that all 6 repositorys belong to the same user.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your objection to the github cli?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not like CLI interface open you browser, open URL: https://github.com/settings/admin and click on button "Start export:
[image]
If you want automatic way use CLI

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170139/2908599) as starting point.